# How to create a arraylist or a vector which takes two different data types in java

Tags: java, swing, vector, arraylist

I have created a tool using java.

Everytime I open a page I want save the object of the class along with a unique name related to that tab.

This I want to do because: When ever I want to request active( get focus on ) any page I can get that object and write obj.requestActive() to get the focus on that tab.

To achive this I want to create a vector/arraylist which takes these two objects in every row (i.e  at index 0 it takes object1 and string 1) so I can easily get the object one by searching string 1 and I can get index from there so that I can get the object also...
NOTE: remember "all these objects are the objects of the same class" i.e all these are pages of the same class with differnt outputs they display from db in their fields according to the user clicks a tag

But I haven't worked with multidimensional vectors so I am not aware of how to do it
It will be very helpful If you guys can give me suggestion

If What ever I am doing is lengthy suggest me any solution on this

Thank you

Comment: I think you've described a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a HashMap().  This would work very nicely considering you said the string is a unique name.

If you insist on using an ArrayList, you can create a simple container object, let's call it PageInfo, that contains an object and a string.  Then you can create an ArrayList() object.  In this case, however, searching won't be as trivial as a hash map, and you won't get the free added guarantee that your data structure only contains one of each string.